# How do I know how many planks I have?

Tags: hammerwatch

In order to get the *Worse than Ghosts and Goblins* achievements, I need to collect exactly 9 of the strange planks. My plan is to skip all of the ones from one of the acts while collecting all of them from the others. I usually don't play the entire single-player game in one sitting and there's a possibility that I may have chosen to skip the planks from a previous act or maybe I intended to do this on the last act, but I just can't remember and I may have accidentally missed a plank somewhere anyways. I don't want to have to start over because I screwed this up again so it would be a great benefit to know how many strange planks I have collected before I do the last act. **Is there a way to check how many planks I have? Maybe by inspecting the save file or through something in the interface that I missed?**

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to check how many planks you have, or the work to check would spend more time than playing through the game. I might get some downvotes but this is the answer. Because they are considered secret so you cannot check that in-game.

The save is basically unreadable without certain knowledges of computers, otherwise you will edit it instead of playing through this exciting games.

I would suggest you just take a note whenever you get a plank, in this way you don't have to purposely skip all planks in an act, and you can choose the planks that is easier to obtain.

Good luck.

Comment: I have a fair knowledge of computers - it's more a matter of not knowing how the saves are ordered/formatted that's of issue to me. I have no intention of save editing - I just want to know where I stand so I don't screw it up once again. Unfortunately I tried simply counting and somehow managed to muck it up several times, I believe it is because I don't play all at once or even on consecutive evenings. I often come away with 1 plank too many as all planks are easy to obtain so I must purposely skip a select group. Since I need to skip exactly 3 and there are 3 in an act, it makes sense.

Comment: If you feel like skipping one act is easier then go ahead. It is just me feel like counting to 9 is easier than skipping an entire act.